# Delete Row from html table on icon click using flask, python, and sqlite

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm at a total loss on how to do this. I'm building a webpage and I need to be able to delete a record from my SQLite database once the user clicks the delete icon on the front end. Can someone please help me figure out how to do this? I have no experience using PHP so any reference to that just won't be helpful. As you can see from the entries page a user will be able to see all entries entered already; each entry_id is unique. If a user clicks delete, then I want the row deleted from the entries page, and also deleted from the DB. If a user clicks the edit button that's another beast, and I'd like to be able to show on click, the populated form in edit mode, and once a user makes changes and click save, then have those changes updated in the DB as well.

Here's my html code:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    index
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

{% if msg %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> {{ msg }}
</div>
{% endif %}
<div>
<form method="POST" action="/entries">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-auto"> ID </th>
                <!--<th class="col-auto" style="display:none;"> entryid</th>-->
                <th class="col-auto"> Edit </th>
                <th class="col-auto"> Delete </th>
                <th class="col-auto">View</th>
                <th class="col-auto">Date</th>
                <th class="left">Title</th>
                <th class="left">Notes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody >

            {% for row in entrylist %}
                <tr>
                    <td id="{{row.entry_id}}"></td>
                    <!--<td style="display:none;" id="{{row.entry_id}}"> {{row.entry_id}}-->
                    <td> <a title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn" id="{{row.entry_id}}"><i class="bi bi-pencil-fill"> </i></a></td>
                    <td> <a class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="delete" id="{{row.entry_id}}"><i class="bi bi-trash" style="color:red;"></i></a></td>
                    <td> <a class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" title = "view" id="{{row.entry_id}}"><i class="bi bi-journals"></i></a></td>
                    <td id="{{row.entry_id}}"> {{row.entry_dt}}</td>
                    <td class="ellipsistd" id="{{row.entry_id}}"> {{row.title }} </td>
                    <td class="ellipsis" id ="{{row.entry_id}}">{{row.notes }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's my flask code:

```
@app.route("/entries", methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def entries():
if request.method == "GET":
    entrylist = db.execute ("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id = ? AND entry_dt <> '' ORDER BY entry_id", session["user_id"])
    # print(entrylist)
    return render_template ("entries.html", entrylist = entrylist)
```

Comment: Write a delete function on your flask just like how you wrote for entries and then call that api through your php code and pass the id through it

Answer (score 0):

I did as suggested and wrote a delete function on flask that deletes the row from my db. On the front end, i just did a jquery to remove row from the view.